# Android Studio Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.2-froyo

Today I downloaded Android Studio. I've installed everything.

Now I wanted to start it but nothing happens. I searched on the Internet and already created system variables "JAVA_HOME" and "ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK" to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40".

Still nothing happens. I have already reinstalled it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you updated the android Studio.

Comment: update it ? I just downloaded it. And I can't open it. I installed the latest from: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html